# Помогите устранить error CS1061 в коде

Tags: c#, unity3d, visual-studio, разработка-игр

Хотел сделать бесконечную игру-runner но появились две одинаковые ошибки `CS1061` в разных строках кода:

```
(19,42):error CS1061:'Player' does not contain a definition for 'health' and no accessible extension method 'health' a first argument of type 'Player' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  

(20,52):error CS1061:'Player' does not contain a definition for 'health' and no accessible extension method 'health' a first argument of type 'Player' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Вот код препятствий:

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Pumpkin : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int damage = 1;
    public float speed;

    private void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector2.left * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player")) 
        {
             // игрок получает урон 
            other.GetComponent<Player>().health -= damage;  здесь error CS1061
            Debug.Log(other.GetComponent<Player>().health); здесь error CS1061
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Вот код игрока(Player):

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector2 targetPos;
    public float Yincrement;

    public float speed;
    public float maxHeight;
    public float minHeight;

    public int health = 3;

    private void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && transform.position.y < maxHeight)
        {
            targetPos = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + Yincrement);

        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow) && transform.position.y > minHeight)
        {
            targetPos = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - Yincrement);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Странно, сунул оба ваших файла к себе в проект и все определилось. По сути ошибка указывает что свойство health отсутствует, но он там есть. Указаны все using файлов? Pumpkin ссылается на верный Player?

Comment: Есть подозрение, что у вас в проекте несколько классов "Player". Нужно указать правильное пространство имен.